# ASP.NET DefaultButton is focused on page load

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm setting the propriety `DefaultButton` on my asp form, in order to send the form on the key `Enter`.

Everything is working fine, but my button has the focus state on the page load which is bothering because of some CSS styles applied on the page.

```
<form id="loginForm" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
    ...
</form>
```

I would like the button to not be focused on the page load.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of default button in ASP.NET. What you can do to override that is to set default focus manually on some other control. To do so, call `Page.SetFocus`:

```
Page.SetFocus(SomeOtherControlID);
```

This will set focus control on the form like that:

```
<form id="loginForm" runat="server"
      DefaultFocus="SomeOtherControlID"
      DefaultButton="btnLogin">
```